# Change parent element with selector css

Tags: html, css, parent-child, selector

I want to make a text input in a form block. I want when the placeholder is not showed (so with #myid:not(:placeholder-shown)) a h1 title change his background color. The problem is that my h1 title is not inside the form block but directly in the body block. Do you know a symbol like this one `>` but that select a parent element ?
I want something like this assuming `<` is a " parent selector ": 
`#myid < #hisparentid < #theparentidofmyid'sparent > #myh1id`

Comment: As of now CSS dont have a selector for selecting the parent. You can view this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: you will need javascript to select a parent to apply style to :(

Comment: Corn on the cob yeah thnx